# Python(not Javascript) html.unescape() got RangeError: Invalid string length

Tags: python, html

I want to decode the following txt document (https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1772016/000177201620000018/0001772016-20-000018.txt), which is in HTML format, using `html.unescape` function.

I have downloaded the txt file as "0001772016-20-000018.txt" before decoding

My code as follow:

```py
from html import unescape
with open (r"D:\0001772016-20-000018.txt","r",encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore') as f:
    text = f.read().replace('\n', '')
text_html=unescape(text)
print(text_html)
```

Then I received the following error message: `RangeError: Invalid string length`

The `unescape()` works fine in my other txt documents but not this one. Can anyone help me to figure out what caused this and how to fix it?

Comment: I have no errors. What system and python version are you running?

I did run it on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python3.8

Comment: I use Python3.8.5/Windows; I find that it is the print() function that causes the problem. If I use `text_html` rather than `print(text_html)`, it does give me the full text. However, the text is still messy with lots of "\t" ...